# How to delete markers from map if i deleted from database

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have an "real time" google maps displaying markers on map when i add or update an user location. Adding/update new user is working good it shows new markers on map but if i delete an entry from database the marker does not dissapear from the map.

If you see any error in my code or if you can help me modifying it i would really appreciate. Thank you

```
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
    var locations = {}; //A repository for markers (and the data from which they were contructed).

    //initial data set for markers
    var locs = {
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      zoom: 9,
      maxZoom: 21,
      minZoom: 1,
      streetViewControl: false,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.7533, 75.8937),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    function setMarkers(locObj) {
      $.each(locObj, function (key, loc) {
        if (!locations[key] && loc.lat !== undefined && loc.lng !== undefined) {
          //Marker has not yet been made (and there's enough data to create one).
          //Create marker
          loc.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lng),
            //icon: 'logo.png', //Marker icon).
            map: map
          });

          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          infowindow.setContent('<span style="color:#EA2E49;font-weight:bold">'+loc.info+'</span>');
          infowindow.open(map, loc.marker);

          //Attach click listener to marker
          google.maps.event.addListener(loc.marker, 'click', (function (key) {
            return function () {
              infowindow.setContent(locations[key].info);
              infowindow.open(map, locations[key].marker);
            }
          })(key));

          //Remember loc in the `locations` so its info can be displayed and so its marker can be deleted.
          locations[key] = loc;
        } else if (locations[key] && loc.remove) {
          //Remove marker from map
          if (locations[key].marker) {
            locations[key].marker.setMap(null);
          }
          //Remove element from 'locations'
          delete locations[key];
        } else if (locations[key]) {
          //Update the previous data object with the latest data.
          $.extend(locations[key], loc);
          if (loc.lat !== undefined && loc.lng !== undefined) {
            //Update marker position (maybe not necessary but doesn't hurt).
            locations[key].marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lng));
        }

        //locations[key].info looks after itself.
      }
    });
  }


  var ajaxObj = { //Object to save cluttering the namespace.
    options: {
      url: "test.php", //The resource that delivers loc data.
      dataType: "json" //The type of data tp be returned by the server.
    },
    delay: 500, //(milliseconds) the interval between successive gets.
    errorCount: 0, //running total of ajax errors.
    errorThreshold: 5, //the number of ajax errors beyond which the get cycle should cease.
    ticker: null, //setTimeout reference - allows the get cycle to be cancelled with clearTimeout(ajaxObj.ticker);
    get: function () { //a function which initiates
      if (ajaxObj.errorCount < ajaxObj.errorThreshold) {
        ajaxObj.ticker = setTimeout(getMarkerData, ajaxObj.delay);
      }
    },
    fail: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(errorThrown);
      ajaxObj.errorCount++;
    }
  };
  //Ajax master routine
  function getMarkerData() {
    $.ajax(ajaxObj.options)
    .done(setMarkers) //fires when ajax returns successfully
    .fail(ajaxObj.fail) //fires when an ajax error occurs
    .always(ajaxObj.get); //fires after ajax success or ajax error
  }

  setMarkers(locs); //Create markers from the initial data set served with the document.

  ajaxObj.get(); //Start the get cycle.
}
</script>
```

Comment: I think you need to remove all the markers from the Map before adding the next set of markers from the subsequent ajax calls others wise the existing markers will still be shown.

Comment: no, i update existing markers and it's working good, but it does not delete them. I don't want to delete all markers and reload them at each ajax call.

Comment: You are adding new Marker objects to the map not updating them.  You need to clear all markers from the maps and then re-add them with the new data.  This will then 'delete' the markers as they are not given in the new dataset

Comment: I think that when you delete a user, the location is simply missing in the data, while your system seems to expect a location with `loc.remove` set to true or equivalent. If i am right, this is server-side that this must be corrected.

Comment: you are right @Kaddath, i fixed it and it's working perfect thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to delete markers :

```
function removeMarkers(){
    for(i=0; i<gMarkersToRemove.length; i++){
        gMarkersToRemove[i].setMap(null);
    }
}
```

Or you can simply hide it so you don't have to reload the map for theirs visibilities :

```
gMarkersToRemove[i].setVisible(false);
```

Or removing the markers completely  :

```
map.removeMarker(map.gMarkersToRemove[i]);
```